# How to get Maxima to properly simplify output

Tags: maxima

For the record, I am new to Maxima so I haven't used it for very long.

I am trying to compute the following symbolic single integral with respect to y1:

```
integrate( 1 / sqrt( (x-x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2 )^3, y1 )
```

where x, x1, y and y1 are all real variables, and away from the singularity points.

When I execute this in Maxima, and I specify that x-x1 is non-zero, I get this over-complicated expression:

```
(%o1)   (4*y1)/((4*(y^2+x1^2-2*x*x1+x^2)-4*y^2)*sqrt(y1^2-2*y*y1+y^2+x1^2-2*x*x1+x^2))-(4*y)/((4*(y^2+x1^2-2*x*x1+x^2)-4*y^2)*sqrt(y1^2-2*y*y1+y^2+x1^2-2*x*x1+x^2))
```

Is there a way to simplify this expression? I know you can factorize some elements, and the denominator is the same in both terms

I have checked Maxima's output by simplifying by hand and comparing to what I get from using Matlab's symbolic toolbox. Matlab gives the following result:

```
                  y - y1
- -------------------------------------
               2           2          2
  sqrt((x - x1)  + (y - y1) ) (x - x1)
```

which is equivalent to Maxima's, except much neater.

Comment: Well, the most widely applicable functions would be `ratsimp`, `expand`, and `factor`; you can also try `radcan` here, since the expression contains a radical. There are a number of poorly-documented and not much used simplification functions in the share folder -- I tried `facsum` and it yields `(y1-y)/((x1-x)^2*sqrt(y1^2-2*y*y1+y^2+x1^2-2*x*x1+x^2))`, which is not too bad.